# SharePoint error movesiteTitle() when ever page loads following error come

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries, sharepoint-designer

ReferenceError: documentGetElementsByName is not defined
MoveSiteTitle();

ReferenceError: MoveSiteTitle is not defined

MoveSiteTitle();

Any help ....!

Comment: I encountered the same problem in the latest version of Chrome (v.23). However when I switched to older version (v.17), the error did not appear. I wonder if it's SharePoint's compatibility issue with Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

Well, seems to be a Chrome related issue as df1 reported. There is one solution however to get rid of the script error if you like.

Put this code inside your master page above the s4-workspace tag or similar:

```
if(typeof documentGetElementsByName==='undefined')
{
    documentGetElementsByName = function(value){
        if($('[name="'+value+'"]'))
        {
            return $('[name="'+value+'"]');
        }
        return null;
    };
}

if(typeof MoveSiteTitle==='undefined')
{
    // Well.... Don't know what this function is supposed to do                           
    // but this way I am avoiding script error...
    MoveSiteTitle = function(value){
        return "";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just javascript basic error.Here documentGetElementsByName(What is the variable name here) Check this variable name and search cant find any where in ur current page. Modify variable name or put some condition over there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that something in your configuration is causing the script that contains the method MoveSiteTitle() to not load.

I was able to obtain the source for the method "MoveSiteTitle" from my dev tools console.  You could alter your master page to include the following JavaScript in the `<head>` section of the master page.

```
if (typeof MoveSiteTitle === 'undefined') {         
        function MoveSiteTitle() {
            a:;
            var b = documentGetElementsByName("titlewpTitleArea");
            if (b == null || b[0] == null) return;
            var a = b[0],
                c = documentGetElementsByName("onetidProjectPropertyTitle");
            if (c == null || c[0] == null) return;
            var e = c[0],
                d = document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleSeparator");
            if (d == null) return;
            if (Boolean(a.insertAdjacentElement)) {
                a.insertAdjacentElement("afterBegin", d);
                a.insertAdjacentElement("afterBegin", e)
            } else {
                a.insertBefore(d, a.firstChild);
                a.insertBefore(e, a.firstChild)
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I found the MoveSiteTitle method (for Sharepoint 2013) in the following file within the hive  (hive 15).

V:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\IE55UP.js

You might be able to debug your specific configuration from there.

Also, the script for GetElementsByName is...

```
function GetElementsByName(b) {
    var a = document.getElementsByName(b);
    if (a.length == 0 && Boolean(window.XMLHttpRequest)) a = FFGetElementsById(document, b);
    return a
}
```